# Facing redirect loop when try to redirect a route through middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-10

I am trying to make a custom authentication system using Laravel 8. For this purpose, I want to check if the user exists in the session; when the user is not found, I want to redirect to a custom login route through middleware. But when I redirect through the middleware, I face an infinite loop of redirects. I have tried the following code.

**Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class atms_auth
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! Session::has('atms_user')) {
            return redirect()->route('/atms/system/login');
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/atms/system/login',
    [App\Http\Controllers\Atms\LoginController::class, 'login'])
    ->name('atms/system/login');
Route::post('/atms/system/verifylogin',
    [App\Http\Controllers\Atms\LoginController::class, 'verifyLogin'])
    ->name('atms/system/verifylogin');
```

I have a controller named `facultyController`. In the constructor of that controller, I have called the middleware.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\faculties;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Departments;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Redirect;

class facultyController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('atms_auth');
    }
```

Comment: please add some more info, like what routes are you accessing ? i would show the whole web.php file and the controller also

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments to your middleware and routes to fix the issue of infinite redirect.

Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AtmsAuth
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->route()->named('atms/system/login')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if (!Session::has('atms_user')) {
            return redirect()->route('atms/system/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // other middleware
    'atms_auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AtmsAuth::class,
];
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/atms/system/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Atms\LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('atms/system/login');
```